# LibGDX Gradle: Export .jar without packed resources

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, export, desktop

The desktop project's `build.gradle` file looks like the following...

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = [ "../core/assets" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.rin.desktop.ClientLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../core/assets");
project.buildDir = '/Users/lukassongajlo/Dropbox/Elementar/Implementation/Test Versions/Client Version'

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar

}


dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/core/assets'
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

... and after running `gradlew desktop:dist` I get the following folder structure...

[image]

**[Question]:** In `libs` is a standalone .jar (see picture below), so there is no need for the other resources. Is there a way to get only this .jar file without this whole folder structure? Big thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These build directories are needed to create the jar file, so you can't go without them completely. But you shure can **delete them after the build finished**.

You can try like this:

```
// ...

// your 'dist' task stays untouched
task dist(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}

task deleteUnusedBuildDirs(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/classes';
    delete 'build/generated';
    delete 'build/resources';
    delete 'build/tmp';
}

dist.finalizedBy deleteUnusedBuildDirs

//...
```